# Pr2 simulation speed

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.
Does anyone know if there is an easy way to speed up the performance of a simulation of a PR2 robot in gazebo?
Has anyone tried to execute some nodes, like the navigation nodes on different machines? Any other experience?
Would be great if someone could share his/her experience!

Best,
Reini

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29124/pr2-simulation-speed/) by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two ways: More power for gazebo or less precision.

The first will be exactly what you said. Run everything on separate machines or cores.
For me, there was a dramatic change switching from a dual core to a hex core machine.

If you cannot do that adjust the stepTime parameter in the physics section of the world.
Obviously once you get it too rough it will become very unstable, but as long as you don't need it as physically correct as possible, but just look believable that is viable.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on 2012-03-05**:
Hello. Thank you for your quick reply. Could you please be more specific where to set the mentioned parameter?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-03-05**:
It is in the world file.

**Comment by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on 2012-03-05**:
Ok found it. Thanks a lot